# MongoDB merge one field into existing collection with Map/Reduce

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mapreduce, mongoose

I have a MongoDB database with 2 collections:

- groups: { group_slug, members }
- users: { id, display name, groups }

All changes to groups are done by changing the members array of the group to include the users ids.

I want to sync these changes across to the users collection by using map/reduce. How can I output the results of map/reduce into an existing collection (but *not* merging or reducing).

My existing code is here: https://gist.github.com/morgante/5430907

Comment: As MapReduce cannot make changes to existing collections or documents, you'd need to do it as a second step (read the mapreduce results and apply them to your existing collection).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I output the results of map/reduce into an existing collection

You really can't do it this way. Nor is this really suggested behaviour. There are other solutions:

Solution #1:

- Output the map / reduce into a temporary collection
- Run a follow-up task that updates the primary data store from the temporary collection
- Clean-up the temporary collection

Honestly, this is a safe way to do this. You can implement some basic retry logic in the whole loop.

Solution #2:

- Put the change on a Queue. (*i.e. "user subscribes to group"*)
- Update both tables from separates workers that are listening for such events on the queue.

This solution may require a separate piece (the queue), but any large system is going to have such denormalization problems. So this will not be the only place you see this.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using solution 1.